Rendering Threejs serverside to generate dynamic images
In my current project, I made an application that runs serverside with Node.js, Three.js and Express.js, and is able to render an image of a 3D scene based on a HTTP request. I managed to get this to work using chromium to render the browser and puppeteer to take screenshots, and a whole lot of duct tape fixes.
How it currently works: it gets the url parameters of the request, loads the correct 3d object and background images, renderes the canvas in the serverside browser with chromium, uses puppeteer to take a screenshot of the serverside browser, adds another image on top of the screenshot and sends the image as a response. The time between sending the request and getting the response is a couple of seconds because of, probably, the inefficient way of coding and not caching anything.

The current output image, this is one of the possible outputs (different backgrounds, persons, etc.)
My goal is to improve this project by implementing a framework or library that is optimised to do stuff like this. I saw Next.js does serverside rendering, but it does not support WebGL (as far as I can find). Is there anything else that I can try to optimize this project?

Why does this need to happen on the server? Can't you just generate the image in the browser? https://threejs.org/manual/#en/tips#screenshot
